# Python - multiprocessing and monkey patching way safety ? (best monkey patching method may born from my idea)

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I'm writing a proxy software, this proxy software support all standard aready, but now the hardest problem, "socks proxy per domain/url (if '???' in self.host: do socks'" without break the whole script by using monkey patching method, I must use monkey patching method because it is the best without any error so far, but if I use that method, my proxy will use that socks server to download all page, not only pages that I want to use socks proxy only because simply monkey patching method "socket" change the whole socket library and make the whole socket library use that socks proxy, and httplib, urllib based on socket library.

https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

```
import urllib2
import socket
import socks

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost")
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

urllib2.urlopen("http://www.somesite.com/") # All requests will pass through the SOCKS proxy
```

I must use monkey patch anyway, opener.open method from that page break a lot page like redirect 30x forever, TLSv1 error.... but the monkey patch is "perfect", no bug, no anything, just work but the whole local proxy will use the socks proxy which is overkill, I want to use socks proxy per page.

After day after day non-stop thinking, I figure something, "If I create a new fresh process using multiprocessing, and then monkey patch socket of that process, urlopen to get content from the domain/url like above without affect my local proxy main process and return the content to my main process and just use that content to display to my web browser, that is just great!"

My method is almost like: "I have a proxy listen at 127.0.0.1:1111 and create another proxy listen at 127.0.0.1:2222, the proxy with port 2222 will be monkey patched socket library to make it download page using my socks proxy, and every time I want to use my socks proxy I will chain my 1111 proxy with 2222 proxy".

Plus if that monkey patching method can be done, probably we can do bandwidth throttle by monkey patching socket and more without break the main process.

My idea may be the born of the greatest monkey patch ever, please help me, I will really appreciate if you can help me write something like demo code.

Comment: I found this question incomprehensible.   If English is not your first language (or even if it is) you may want to get someone to proof-read and edit it for you, so that each sentence makes sense.   Also, read the guidelines for how to ask a good question at [help].

Comment: Thank you, what I should edit to make my post readable ? Thank you.

I think it is not that hard to understand, I try to repeat and repeat my problem to make my question easier to understand.

Simply:
"The way to use multiprocessing create child process to download page with urllib.urlopen using pySocks (monkey patching method "socket.socket = socks.socksocket") to fake my IP Address and return page content to my parent process"

Comment: It might be more than I can help you with in comments.  The sentence you wrote in your comment is more understandable than any in the question.   It is at least shorter.  The first sentence in your question goes for a whole paragraph - that is too long to be undertood - you are stringing together your thoughts, not stating them clearly.   And what is the strange "(if '???;" set of characters - with unmatched paren?  Rather than answer my question in comments, I recommend trying to rewrite your question with concise statements.   Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay, I will answer my own question now!

Comment: Thank you, I learnt that! And I will someday learn how to write an easier to understand question.

Answer (score -1):

And here is my answer for my question, thank everybody:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import urllib.request

def foo(q):
    #q.put("123")
    import socks
    import socket
    socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 10080)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip")
    #print("123")
    q.put(r.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
    r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip")
    print(r.read())
```

This way will create an isolated process and monkey patch socket library from that process.

Output from ILDE:

```
b'{\n  "origin": "xxx.148.2.18"\n}\n'
b'{\n  "origin": "xx.xxx.113.133"\n}\n'
```